# Tensorflow: Fine-Tuning the VGG19 Model [Python]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have VGG19 Model.

Can it be used `fine_tune_at = 100` ???

Is it correct ???

I don't understand fine-tuning method.

I'm a newbie in both deep learning and tensorflow.

Can someone please explain to me ???

Thank you.

```
vgg_model.trainable = True
```

fine tuning the vgg19 model unfreeze top layers/freeze

```
print("Number of layers in the base model: ", len(vgg_model.layers))

fine_tune_at = 100

for layer in vgg_model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
  layer.trainable = False

Number of layers in the base model:  22
```

compiling the model

```
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

summary detail model

```
model.summary()

Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 block1_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
                                                                 
 block1_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
                                                                 
 block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
                                                                 
 block2_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
                                                                 
 block2_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
                                                                 
 block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 block3_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
                                                                 
 block3_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_conv4 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
                                                                 
 block4_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
                                                                 
 block4_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_conv4 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
                                                                 
 block5_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv4 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d (G  (None, 512)              0         
 lobalAveragePooling2D)                                          
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 128)               65664     
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 129       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 20,090,177
Trainable params: 65,793
Non-trainable params: 20,024,384
```

num trainable_variables

```
len(model.trainable_variables)

4
```

Comment: Sorry but "I can used fine_tune_at = 100 ???" does not make sense grammatically and as a question, you should clarify.

Comment: This thread may help you to become familiar with the concept: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331369/what-is-meant-by-fine-tuning-of-neural-network, and from there you may get to https://flyyufelix.github.io/2016/10/08/fine-tuning-in-keras-part2.html.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wondering fine_tune_at can It be 100 ?? or must be less than 22 ??

Comment: @Roseanne What you do in the line `for layer in vgg_model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:` and the line after that is to freeze the weights of the first `fine_tune_at` layers of the base model. You cannot use `fine_tune_at = 100` since your base model does not have 100 layers.